# Set edittext value onCreate inside fragment

Tags: android

I'm trying to set `EditText` value when activity is starting, here is what I'm doing:

```
      @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SharedPreferences mPrefs = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("userinfoafterlogin", MODE_PRIVATE); //add key
            String response = mPrefs.getString("userinfo", null);

            try{
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
                json = (JSONObject)json.get("nameValuePairs");
                json = (JSONObject)json.get("userData");
                json = (JSONObject)json.get("nameValuePairs");
                String fullname = (String)json.get("fullname");
                String username = (String)json.get("username");

                EditText editText = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fullnametext);
                editText.setText(fullname);

                Log.i("data", " retrieve --> " + fullname);
            }catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("MYAPP", "unexpected JSON exception", e);
            }
  }
```

But, when I run it, I get this error

> 12-29 14:29:48.321 3273-3273/com.example.boby.srsly E/AndroidRuntime:
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                         Process: com.example.boby.srsly, PID: 3273
>                                                                         java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                             at
>   com.example.boby.srsly.ProfilFragment.onCreate(ProfilFragment.java:71)
>                                                                             at android.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1678)
>                                                                             at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:859)
>                                                                             at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
>                                                                             at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
>                                                                             at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
>                                                                             at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
>                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5019)
>                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                             at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>                                                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

How can i fix it ?

I moved it inside `onCreateView`

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profil, container, false);
    SharedPreferences mPrefs = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("userinfoafterlogin", MODE_PRIVATE); //add key
    String response = mPrefs.getString("userinfo", null);

    try{
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
        json = (JSONObject)json.get("nameValuePairs");
        json = (JSONObject)json.get("userData");
        json = (JSONObject)json.get("nameValuePairs");
        String fullname = (String)json.get("fullname");
        String username = (String)json.get("username");

        EditText editText = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.fullnametext);
        editText.setText(fullname);
        Log.i("data", " retrieve --> " + fullname);
        return v;
    }catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("MYAPP", "unexpected JSON exception", e);
        return v;
    }

}
```

Now I got this error

> 12-29 14:35:09.801 3383-3383/com.example.boby.srsly E/AndroidRuntime:
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                         Process: com.example.boby.srsly, PID: 3383
>                                                                         java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView cannot be cast to
>   android.widget.EditText
>                                                                             at
>   com.example.boby.srsly.ProfilFragment.onCreateView(ProfilFragment.java:78)
>                                                                             at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
>                                                                             at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
>                                                                             at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
>                                                                             at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
>                                                                             at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
>                                                                             at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
>                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5019)
>                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                             at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>                                                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Is it fragment?

Comment: @R2R yes it is, it's a fragment

Comment: try moving the codes for updating the View to onCreateView instead of onCreate.

Comment: @AngelKoh said correctly  you have to move your code to oncreateView()

Comment: @R2R Please check my updated question,

Comment: post your `fragment_profil.xml` file.

Comment: `fullnametext` in `fragment_profil.xml` should be `EditText` and I think you have declared it as  `AppCompatTextView`. So it it the problem.

Comment: @Dharmishtha ah,i need to stop `copy paste` too much. Thanks

Comment: means it is the Problem right?

Comment: @Bossby take a look at my answer, I have updated the code you need to correct and yes you need to stop copy paste :P

Comment: @Bossby it is for your help that try to read Exception Detail and most of times it clarify the problem. So you are able to solve your own normal problem .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to learn about the `fragment` life cycle [Fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html). In onCreate of fragment the view is not created. The view is created in `onCreateView` method of fragment

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourView, container, false);
 editText = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.fullnametext);
        editText.setText(fullname);
}
```

So you need to move your layout widgets in this method.

And about your second error you are probably casting the wrong widget:

> **EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.boby.srsly, PID: 3383 java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText**

So you need to do it like this:

```
AppCompatTextView textview;
textview= (AppCompatTextView )v.findViewById(R.id.fullnametext);
            textview.setText(fullname);
```

Or if it's the edittext you want then you need to change your `AppCompatTextView` to `EditText`

Comment: `editText = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.fullnametext);`

Answer (score 0):

First you need to override `onActivityCreated()`method in your `fragment` and initialize the `EditText` inside on `activitycreated()` method.

```
EditText editText ;
```

like this

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    editText = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fullnametext);
            editText.setText(fullname);
}
```